# How do I access object properties based on user input from function within an object?

Tags: javascript

How do I access object properties based on user input from function within an object?
I want to call weight with "martin" as a paramenter and return "martin"s weight.
take this as an example:

```
const data = {
  info: [
    {name: "martin", weight: "2kg"},
  ],
  weight(name){
    return this.name[name].weight;
  },
};

console.log(data.weight("martin"));
```

Comment: What is expected output.

Comment: @MaheerAli Thanks, fixed!

Comment: Expected output is: 2kg

Comment: I want the code to work with more objects

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment of OP:

> I want to be able to access the name property of data.

For this you will need to restructure you data and make it object. And you can't have same names too in this case. Below is an example.

```js
const data = {
  info: {
    martin:{weight: "2kg"},
    jack:{weight: "5kg"},
  },
  weight(name){
    return this.info[name].weight
  },
};

console.log(data.weight("martin"));
console.log(data.weight("jack"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access it by name, you can restructure your data and use the name as follows:

```
 const data = {
  info: {
    martin: { weight: "2kg"},
  },
  weight: function (name) {
    return this.info[name].weight || null;
  },
};

console.log(data.weight("martin"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the question

> I want to call weight with "martin" as a paramenter and return "martin"s weight

To do that you will need to use `.find` because `info` is an array.

If you find it, you can access `.weight`.

This line `return info ? info.weight : null;` is important so you don't get an error of `Unable to access property weight of null or undefined`

```js
    const data = {
      info: [
        {name: "martin", weight: "2kg"},
      ],
      weight(name){
        let info = this.info.find(x => x.name == name)       
        return info ? info.weight : null;
      },
    };
    
    console.log(data.weight("martin"));
```

Comment: I don't want to do it this way. I want to be able to access the name property of data. I didnt downvote you.

Comment: Your code it fine can't say why its downvoted. Add some explanation.

Comment: @LukaMomcilovic There is not name property of data its and array. You need to restructure it and make it object if you want to access it that way.

Comment: @LukaMomcilovic if this isn't what you want, please edit your question, because this is the only way to do what you said.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to return weight of every object with "martin" as name :

```js
const data = {
  info: [
    {name: "martin", weight: "2kg"},
    {name: "alex", weight: "3kg"},
    {name: "martin", weight: "12kg"},
  ],
  getAll(name) {
    return this.info.filter(obj => obj.name == name);
  },
  weight(name){
    return this.getAll(name).map(obj => obj.weight);
  },
};

console.log(data.weight("martin"));
```